# Cómo puedo leer un archivo csv con tíldes?

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, tildes

estoy trabajando con un archivo csv y a la hora de cargar el fichero y leerlo, todas las palabras que llevan tilde no me cargan correctamente.
Lo estoy intentando leer en RStudio y he usado la función read.csv2:

```
read.csv2("ADSL.csv")
```

Pero el resultado de la consola me sale asÍ:

```
11 Almer\xeda   4011     Alhama de Almer\xeda      909   26   652      3824
```

Estoy trabajando en MacBook, con mac os x el capitan, 10.11.6

Comment: Primero tendrás que decodificarlo, esto especificando en que codificación esta, y luego lo lees

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaron arriba, prueba a leerlo especificando en que codificación está.

Te recomiendo usar la funcion fread de la libreria data.table

```
library(data.table)

fread("ADSL.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Tendrías que saber en que codificación se guardo el archivo, pero por lo general es la UTF-8 o
Latin-1

Answer (score 0):

También puedes mirar si tus opciones globales en tools, esta indicado por defecto UTF-8, así no tendrás que cambiarlo siempre desde fread. Espero que te funcione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]